# Rails 4 not executing $(document).ready(ready); function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

**SOLUTION**

I had both a `users.js` and `users.coffee` in my asset pipeline. Apparently `users.coffee` was preventing `users.js` from being loaded. Make sure you delete it!

---

I'm trying to implement [this](http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/gmail-like-chat-application-in-ruby-on-rails) -- github repo [here](https://github.com/Joseph-N/chatty).

There are two JS files that are required to start chats -- `chat.js` and `users.js`. Both include `$(document).ready(ready);` functions. Only I can only get Rails to execute `chat.js`

I have confirmed by adding a `console.log("confirm");` just inside both functions like so...

```
var ready = function () {
  console.log("success") ...
```

I've tried both of these...

```
$(document).on("page:load", ready);
$(document).on("page:change", ready);
```

I have tried adding this to the `application.html.erb` ==> `<%= javascript_include_tag "users", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`

I have tried adding `//= require users` to `application.js`

I've tried adding this to `config/initializer/assets.rb` ==> `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( users.js )`

Why isn't the `ready` function executing inside `users.js`?

My code repo is [here](https://github.com/KendallWeihe/chatty_app).

Here is `chat.js`...

```
/**
 * Chat logic
 *
 * Most of the js functionality is inspired from anatgarg.com
 * jQuery tag Module from the tutorial
 * http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/
 *
 */


var chatboxFocus = new Array();
var chatBoxes = new Array();

var ready = function () {
  console.log("success1");

    chatBox = {
        // console.log("success");

        /**
         * creates an inline chatbox on the page by calling the
         * createChatBox function passing along the unique conversation_id
         *
         * @param conversation_id
         */

        chatWith: function (conversation_id) {
          console.log("success1");

            chatBox.createChatBox(conversation_id);
            $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxtextarea").focus();
        },

        /**
         * closes the chatbox by essentially hiding it from the page
         *
         * @param conversation_id
         */

        close: function (conversation_id) {
            $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id).css('display', 'none');
            chatBox.restructure();
        },

        /**
         * Plays a notification sound when a new chat message arrives
         */

        notify: function () {
            var audioplayer = $('#chatAudio')[0];
            audioplayer.play();
        },

        /**
         * Handles 'smart layouts' of the chatboxes. Like when new chatboxes are
         * added or removed from the view, it restructures them so that they appear
         * neatly aligned on the page
         */

        restructure: function () {
            align = 0;
            for (x in chatBoxes) {
                chatbox_id = chatBoxes[x];

                if ($("#chatbox_" + chatbox_id).css('display') != 'none') {
                    if (align == 0) {
                        $("#chatbox_" + chatbox_id).css('right', '20px');
                    } else {
                        width = (align) * (280 + 7) + 20;
                        $("#chatbox_" + chatbox_id).css('right', width + 'px');
                    }
                    align++;
                }
            }

        },

        /**
         * Takes in two parameters. It is responsible for fetching the specific conversation's
         * html page and appending it to the body of our home page e.g if conversation_id = 1
         *
         * $.get("conversations/1, function(data){
         *    // rest of the logic here
         * }, "html")
         *
         * @param conversation_id
         * @param minimizeChatBox
         */

        createChatBox: function (conversation_id, minimizeChatBox) {
          console.log("success2");
            if ($("#chatbox_" + conversation_id).length > 0) {
                if ($("#chatbox_" + conversation_id).css('display') == 'none') {
                    $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id).css('display', 'block');
                    chatBox.restructure();
                }
                $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxtextarea").focus();
                return;
            }

            $("body").append('<div id="chatbox_' + conversation_id + '" class="chatbox"></div>')

            $.get("conversations/" + conversation_id, function (data) {
                $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id).html(data);
                $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxcontent").scrollTop($("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);
            }, "html");

            $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id).css('bottom', '0px');

            chatBoxeslength = 0;

            for (x in chatBoxes) {
                if ($("#chatbox_" + chatBoxes[x]).css('display') != 'none') {
                    chatBoxeslength++;
                }
            }

            if (chatBoxeslength == 0) {
                $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id).css('right', '20px');
            } else {
                width = (chatBoxeslength) * (280 + 7) + 20;
                $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id).css('right', width + 'px');
            }

            chatBoxes.push(conversation_id);

            if (minimizeChatBox == 1) {
                minimizedChatBoxes = new Array();

                if ($.cookie('chatbox_minimized')) {
                    minimizedChatBoxes = $.cookie('chatbox_minimized').split(/\|/);
                }
                minimize = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < minimizedChatBoxes.length; j++) {
                    if (minimizedChatBoxes[j] == conversation_id) {
                        minimize = 1;
                    }
                }

                if (minimize == 1) {
                    $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id + ' .chatboxcontent').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id + ' .chatboxinput').css('display', 'none');
                }
            }

            chatboxFocus[conversation_id] = false;

            $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxtextarea").blur(function () {
                chatboxFocus[conversation_id] = false;
                $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxtextarea").removeClass('chatboxtextareaselected');
            }).focus(function () {
                chatboxFocus[conversation_id] = true;
                $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id + ' .chatboxhead').removeClass('chatboxblink');
                $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxtextarea").addClass('chatboxtextareaselected');
            });

            $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id).click(function () {
                if ($('#chatbox_' + conversation_id + ' .chatboxcontent').css('display') != 'none') {
                    $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxtextarea").focus();
                }
            });

            $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id).show();

        },

        /**
         * Responsible for listening to the keypresses when chatting. If the Enter button is pressed,
         * we submit our conversation form to our rails app
         *
         * @param event
         * @param chatboxtextarea
         * @param conversation_id
         */

        checkInputKey: function (event, chatboxtextarea, conversation_id) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey == 0) {
                event.preventDefault();

                message = chatboxtextarea.val();
                message = message.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");

                if (message != '') {
                    $('#conversation_form_' + conversation_id).submit();
                    $(chatboxtextarea).val('');
                    $(chatboxtextarea).focus();
                    $(chatboxtextarea).css('height', '44px');
                }
            }

            var adjustedHeight = chatboxtextarea.clientHeight;
            var maxHeight = 94;

            if (maxHeight > adjustedHeight) {
                adjustedHeight = Math.max(chatboxtextarea.scrollHeight, adjustedHeight);
                if (maxHeight)
                    adjustedHeight = Math.min(maxHeight, adjustedHeight);
                if (adjustedHeight > chatboxtextarea.clientHeight)
                    $(chatboxtextarea).css('height', adjustedHeight + 8 + 'px');
            } else {
                $(chatboxtextarea).css('overflow', 'auto');
            }

        },

        /**
         * Responsible for handling the growth of chatboxes as they increase on the page
         * Keeps track of the minimized chatboxes etc
         *
         * @param conversation_id
         */

        toggleChatBoxGrowth: function (conversation_id) {
            if ($('#chatbox_' + conversation_id + ' .chatboxcontent').css('display') == 'none') {

                var minimizedChatBoxes = new Array();

                if ($.cookie('chatbox_minimized')) {
                    minimizedChatBoxes = $.cookie('chatbox_minimized').split(/\|/);
                }

                var newCookie = '';

                for (i = 0; i < minimizedChatBoxes.length; i++) {
                    if (minimizedChatBoxes[i] != conversation_id) {
                        newCookie += conversation_id + '|';
                    }
                }

                newCookie = newCookie.slice(0, -1)


                $.cookie('chatbox_minimized', newCookie);
                $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id + ' .chatboxcontent').css('display', 'block');
                $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id + ' .chatboxinput').css('display', 'block');
                $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxcontent").scrollTop($("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);
            } else {

                var newCookie = conversation_id;

                if ($.cookie('chatbox_minimized')) {
                    newCookie += '|' + $.cookie('chatbox_minimized');
                }


                $.cookie('chatbox_minimized', newCookie);
                $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id + ' .chatboxcontent').css('display', 'none');
                $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id + ' .chatboxinput').css('display', 'none');
            }

        }



    }


    /**
     * Cookie plugin
     *
     * Copyright (c) 2006 Klaus Hartl (stilbuero.de)
     * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
     * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
     * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
     *
     */

    jQuery.cookie = function (name, value, options) {
        if (typeof value != 'undefined') { // name and value given, set cookie
            options = options || {};
            if (value === null) {
                value = '';
                options.expires = -1;
            }
            var expires = '';
            if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == 'number' || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
                var date;
                if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
                    date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                } else {
                    date = options.expires;
                }
                expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString(); // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            }
            // CAUTION: Needed to parenthesize options.path and options.domain
            // in the following expressions, otherwise they evaluate to undefined
            // in the packed version for some reason...
            var path = options.path ? '; path=' + (options.path) : '';
            var domain = options.domain ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : '';
            var secure = options.secure ? '; secure' : '';
            document.cookie = [name, '=', encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join('');
        } else { // only name given, get cookie
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
    };


}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:load", ready);
```

Here is `users.js`...

```
var ready = function () {
  console.log("success");

    /**
     * When the send message link on our home page is clicked
     * send an ajax request to our rails app with the sender_id and
     * recipient_id
     */

    $('.start-conversation').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("success");
        var sender_id = $(this).data('sid');
        var recipient_id = $(this).data('rip');

        $.post("/conversations", { sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id }, function (data) {
            chatBox.chatWith(data.conversation_id);
        });
    });

    /**
     * Used to minimize the chatbox
     */

    $(document).on('click', '.toggleChatBox', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("success1");

        var id = $(this).data('cid');
        chatBox.toggleChatBoxGrowth(id);
    });

    /**
     * Used to close the chatbox
     */

    $(document).on('click', '.closeChat', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("success2");

        var id = $(this).data('cid');
        chatBox.close(id);
    });


    /**
     * Listen on keypress' in our chat textarea and call the
     * chatInputKey in chat.js for inspection
     */

    $(document).on('keydown', '.chatboxtextarea', function (event) {
      console.log("success3");

        var id = $(this).data('cid');
        chatBox.checkInputKey(event, $(this), id);
    });

    /**
     * When a conversation link is clicked show up the respective
     * conversation chatbox
     */

    $('a.conversation').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("success4");

        var conversation_id = $(this).data('cid');
        chatBox.chatWith(conversation_id);
    });


}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:load", ready);
```

`application.js` looks like this...

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require transition.js
//= require alert.js
//= require button.js
//= require carousel.js
//= require collapse.js
//= require dropdown.js
//= require modal.js
//= require tooltip.js
//= require scrollspy.js
//= require tab.js
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require private_pub
//= require chat
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I have this inside the `<head>` tag of `application.html.erb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "users", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Oh and here is the HTML page (for all code see repo)

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- Not implemented on tutorial -->
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div style="height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading">Registered Users</div>

        <!-- Table -->
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <% @users.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= index +=1 %></td>
                <td><%= user.email %></td>
                <td>
                  <%= link_to "Send Message", "#", class: "btn btn-success btn-xs start-conversation",
                              "data-sid" => current_user.id, "data-rip" => user.id %>
                </td>
              </tr>
          <% end %>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
    <hr>
    <h3>Your Conversations</h3>

    <div style="height: 400px; overflow-y: auto;">
      <% if @conversations.any? %>
          <ul class="media-list">
            <% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
                <li class="media">
                  <%= image_tag("http://placehold.it/50x50", class: "media-object pull-left") %>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <%= link_to "", conversation_path(conversation), class: "conversation", "data-cid" => conversation.id %>
                        <h4 class="media-heading"><%= conversation_interlocutor(conversation).email %></h4>
                        <p><%= conversation.messages.last.nil? ? "No messages" : truncate(conversation.messages.last.body, length: 45) %></p>
                  </div>
                </li>

            <% end %>
          </ul>
      <% else %>
          <p>You have no conversations. Click send message with any user to create one.</p>
      <% end %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: is turbolinks enabled?

Comment: It is required in `application.js` and included in the `Gemfile` so I'm thinking yes -- the same as the example repo I'm pulling my code from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your repo and deleted `users.coffee` file:

[image]

Comment: I just posted this

Comment: both found it! **jinx** 

Comment: How do you do emojis here?

Comment: I did it directly from Mac OS